# Calling a function within a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am creating a simple TCP server-client script in Python. The server is threaded and forks a new worker/thread for every client connection. So far I have pretty much coded the entire server module. But my function called the `handle_clients()` which is forked for every incoming client connection is getting very long. In order to improve the readability of the code I want to split my `handle_clients()` into multiple small functions. I do understand that when I split `handle_client()` into smaller functions, the split functions should be wrapped around `mutex locks` to synchronize shared usage between multiple `handle_clients()` threads. Doing this will actually reduce the efficiency of the program because `handle_clients()` will have to wait for other threads to unlock the shared functions before actually using it. My other thought was to create these smaller functions as threads within the `handle_clients()` thread. And wait for these threads to finish using `Thread.join()` before continuing. Is there a better way to do this?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import threading
import pandas as pd

class TCPServer(object):
    NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 0
    BUFFER = 4096
    threads_list = []

    def __init__(self, port, hostname):
        self.socket = socket.socket(
            family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((hostname, port))

    def listen_for_clients(self):
        self.socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.socket.accept()
            client_ID = client.recv(TCPServer.BUFFER)
            print(f'Connected to client: {client_ID}')

            if client_ID:
                TCPServer.NUMBER_OF_THREADS = TCPServer.NUMBER_OF_THREADS + 1
                thread = threading.Thread(
                    target=TCPServer.create_worker, args=(self, client, address, client_ID))
                TCPServer.threads_list.append(thread)
                thread.start()

            if TCPServer.NUMBER_OF_THREADS > 2:
                break

        TCPServer.wait_for_workers()

    def wait_for_workers():
        for thread in TCPServer.threads_list:
            thread.join()


    def create_worker(self, client, address, client_ID):
        print(f'Spawned a new worker for {client_ID}. Worker #: {TCPServer.NUMBER_OF_THREADS}')
        data_list = []
        data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
        client.send("SEND_REQUEST_TYPE".encode())
        request_type = client.recv(TCPServer.BUFFER).decode('utf-8')

        if request_type == 'KMEANS':
            print(f'Client: REQUEST_TYPE {request_type}')
            client.send("SEND_DATA".encode())

            while True:
                data = client.recv(TCPServer.BUFFER).decode('utf-8')
                if data == 'ROW':
                    client.send("OK".encode())
                    while True:
                        data = client.recv(TCPServer.BUFFER).decode('utf-8')
                        print(f'Client: {data}')
                        if data == 'ROW_END':
                            print('Data received: ', data_list)
                            series = pd.Series(data_list)
                            data_frame.append(series, ignore_index=True)
                            data_list = []
                            client.send("OK".encode())
                            break
                        else:
                            data_list.append(int(data))
                            client.send("OK".encode())

                elif data == 'DATA_END':
                    client.send("WAIT".encode())


            # (Vino) pass data to algorithm
            print('Data received from client {client_ID}: ', data_frame)

        elif request_type == 'NEURALNET':
            pass
        elif request_type == 'LINRIGRESSION':
            pass
        elif request_type == 'LOGRIGRESSION':
            pass



def main():
    port = input("Port: ")
    server = TCPServer(port=int(port), hostname='localhost')
    server.listen_for_clients()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note: This following block of code is repetative and will e used multiple times within the `handle_client()` function.

```
while True:
    data = client.recv(TCPServer.BUFFER).decode('utf-8')
    if data == 'ROW':
        client.send("OK".encode())
        while True:
            data = client.recv(TCPServer.BUFFER).decode('utf-8')
            print(f'Client: {data}')
            if data == 'ROW_END':
                print('Data received: ', data_list)
                series = pd.Series(data_list)
                data_frame.append(series, ignore_index=True)
                data_list = []
                client.send("OK".encode())
                break
            else:
                data_list.append(int(data))
                client.send("OK".encode())

    elif data == 'DATA_END':
        client.send("WAIT".encode())


# (Vino) pass data to algorithm
print('Data received from client {client_ID}: ', data_frame)
```

This is the block I want a place in a separate function and calls it within the `handle_client()` thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already long, I'll not dive into it but try to keep things general.

> I do understand that when I split handle_client() into smaller functions, the split functions should be wrapped around mutex locks.

That's not directly true, between threads you already have to use locks to guard against memory overwriting, regarless your function calls.

> The server is threaded

Looks like you're doing CPU-intensive work (I see `LINALG`, `NEURALNET`, ...), it is not logical to use threads, in Python, to dispatch CPU-intensive loads as the GIL will linearize CPU usage between your threads.

The way to parallelize CPU intensive work in Python is to use processes.

Processes do not share memory so you'll be able to manipulate variables freely without mutexes, but they won't be shared at all, I hope your jobs are independent, as they can't share any state.

If you need to share state, avoid locks, it's complicated to handle, it's the way to dead locks, and it's not readable, try to implement your "state sharing" with queues, as a pipeline of jobs, each worker pulling from a queue, doing work, and pushing to another queue, this way keep things clear and easy to understand. Plus there's implementation of queues for threads and processes so you'll be able to switch from both almost seamlessly.

> if TCPServer.NUMBER_OF_THREADS > 2:
>       break

Hey, you're breaking out of your main loop when you have more than two threads, existing your main process, killing your server, I bet that now what you want. Oh and if you use processes instead of threads, you should prefork a pool of them, as their creation costs more than a thread. And reuse them, a process can do a job after finishing one, it does not have to die (typically use [queues](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) to send job to your processes).

Side note: I'd implement this using HTTP instead of raw TCP to benefit from the notions of request, response, error reporting, existing frameworks, and the ability to use existing clients (curl/wget in command line, your browser, `requests` in Python). I'd implement this fully asynchronously (no blocking HTTP request), like one request to create a job, and following requests to get the status and the result, like:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost/linalg/jobs/ -d '{your data}'
201 Created
Location: http://localhost/linalg/jobs/1

$ curl -XGET http://localhost/linalg/jobs/1
200 OK
{"status": "queued"}
```

Some time later…

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost/linalg/jobs/1
200 OK
{"status": "in progress"}
```

Some time later…

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost/linalg/jobs/1
200 OK
{"status": "done", "result": "..."}
```

To implement this there's a lot of nice work already done, typically [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html), [apistar](https://github.com/encode/apistar), and so on.

Comment: Hey man, thank you very much for taking your time to give me a detailed answer. I really appreciate it. I was considering HTTP asynchronous communication but was discouraged by the large matrices of numerical data I am gonna transmit and encoding them as JSON/BSON is quite tedious as well. Whats your opinion in this? Plus you are correct about me exiting the loop when the `NUM_OF_THREADS` > 2. That's not what I want. I didn't actually test that part. I can actually remove the if block, I don't need that. Using process is a good suggestion. I'm reading up on that. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're very welcome. Large chunks of JSON are OK over HTTP don't worry too much about it: HTTP is not encoding them in any way that will make them heavier, so over TCP or over HTTP they will cost the same time and bandwidth. But errors like transmission interruption will (should) be handled properly in your HTTP libraries (client and server). On the other hand, using raw TCP you'll have to handle them yourself. I would appreciate a "mark as answered" if you don't expect other answers on this question.